# How to Get jQuery Confirm (jConfirm) value and check condition with that value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I have use a jQuery Confirm [plugin](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#dialog). In my case jQuery Confirm works well.

But my question is how can I get the return value from my following `jconfirm` function.

Here I want to save the result of `jconfirm` function into confirmVar and then check it with some condition, according the condition it will do some work. But here `confirmVar` can't get the return value of `jconfirm` function.

```js
  if (courseCredit > remainingCredit) {
                    
        //Here confirmVar cant get the return value.
    
                    var confirmVar = jconfirm({                        
                        theme: 'black',
                        title: 'Course Credit Confirmation',
                        content: 'Are you sure to take this Course ?',
                        confirmButton: 'Yes',
                        cancelButton: 'NO'
                    });

                   //Here I want to check confirmVar
                    if (confirmVar==true) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "@Url.Action("AssignCourse", "CourseTeacher")",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { courseTeacher: [deptCode, tchrMail, creditToTake, remainingCredit, courseCode, crseTchrName, courseCredit] },
                            console: log(data),
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {

                            }

                        });
                    }
                    else if(confirmVar == false) {
                      //do nothing
                    }
                    return false;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it something like that;

```
var choose=false;

    $.confirm({
       theme: 'black',
       title: 'Course Credit Confirmation',
       content: 'Are you sure to take this Course ?',
       confirmButton: 'Yes',
       cancelButton: 'NO'
        confirm: function(){
            choose=true;
        },
        cancel: function(){
           choose=false;
        }
    });
```

Define variable at root level of the javascript, and change it with `confirm` or `cancel` states. Hope this works for you.

Update:

```
$.confirm({
  theme: 'black',
  title: 'Course Credit Confirmation',
  content: 'Are you sure to take this Course ?',
  confirmButton: 'Yes',
  cancelButton: 'NO'
  confirm: function(){
  $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("AssignCourse", "CourseTeacher")",
        type: "POST",
        data: { courseTeacher: [deptCode, tchrMail, creditToTake, remainingCredit, courseCode, crseTchrName, courseCredit] },
        console: log(data),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { }
        });
  },
  cancel: function(){
  //do nothing
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry! It doesn't work. `choose` always keep false and `confirm` function run at last. @Qsprec

Comment: so add your ajax request to your confirm option. I will update my answer.

Comment: thanks for your update! But its still not working. My Confirm Dialog box shows for one/two second. Then it just disappear. @Qsprec

Comment: I am using the same plugin in my projects and it works for me. I couldn't manage to understand what is wrong with it in your case.